# Is there a workaround or alternative to IRibbonControl.Context to access the correct window and workbook in Excel 2016 or newer?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, ribbon

There [are existing posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303390/invalidate-ribbon-control-in-excel-2013-for-multiple-workbooks) about related topics, and there are [support requests on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a3dade87-1df7-46ec-8876-437194d7553e/how-to-reference-the-correct-workbook-from-a-control-in-a-ribbon-callback?forum=exceldev) that are unsolved/unrepaired. It sounds like the "right way" doesn't work, so I'm wondering there is a workaround.

Let me describe what I perceive to be "the right way" that doesn't work, and maybe you have an alternative path that will work.

I can create an Excel VSTO plugin in Visual Studio, create a custom Ribbon.xml and Ribbon.cs file, and then open multiple workbooks which appear as different windows. Per other SO posts, I can hook into the `Application_WindowActivate` event and call `Invalidate()` on my ribbon, forcing a refresh of all the callbacks. The ribbon will reflect the state of the Active Window... and so will every other instance of the ribbon in other windows. As a result, the Ribbon that appears in every window is the same Ribbon. If I have a `CheckBox` or a `Button` with a `Pressed` attribute or anything else stateful, those states will propagate to every open Excel window.

This can be avoided by running Excel with the `excel /s` parameter which appears to create a new process with its own SDI - but this is not a user-friendly solution.

It looks like what you're **supposed** to be able to do during an `onAction` ribbon callback is access the `IRibbonControl` parameter's `Context` property, which is supposed to be the correct `Excel.Window` object. In theory this would present either only the Window you are activating, or would execute for each open Window. And with the correct `Context` you could execute functions that provide different states back to the Ribbon. And then maybe in one Excel window, you ribbon could have a `Pressed` `Button`, and in the other window, an unpressed `Button`. Except it doesn't work.

When I call `Invalidate` I get two callbacks (not sure why, the MSDN says it might be a bug) both for the newly activated window, and I execute logic to update the state of active window's ribbon. And then the previous window's ribbon updates the same way.

If this is the way it is, fine. We'll tell our users that they may see some funky Ribbon changes on inactive windows but that it will always be correct on the active window. We can deal with that. But if there **is** a way around this problem that could make it appear as though the Ribbon had different states on a per-workbook/window basis... that'd be really cool.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right avenue. Only the active window gets callbacks invoked and its values refreshed. You must switch to another Excel window if you want your ribbon UI invalidated. For each of the callbacks the add-in implements, the responses are cached. For example, if an add-in writer implements the getImage callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in-place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method.

You may also consider caching UI settings in custom properties. And as soon as a custom property is changed you may trigger UI updates.

Read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Also, you may find the folliwing links helpful:

- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd548010(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd548011(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I am using the samples from these links in order to cache the Ribbon itself. That exposes `Invalidate`, `InvalidateControl`, and `InvalidateControlMso`. Thus far I've only used `Invalidate`.

In my ideal scenario, when switching Excel windows, triggering `Application_WindowActivate`, and calling `Invalidate`, I would execute the action **only** on the active window and the other windows would persist their state. I reviewed these references but am still not sure if I can pursue that goal (in Excel 2016 and newer).

Comment: I did an experiment. I added a `Label` to the Ribbon that on each callback would toggle between two different strings. With two Excel windows open, I called `Invalidate`. My `Label` callback was called twice. The `IRibbonControl.Context` was the newly Active Window both times - but the two windows ended up with different `Label` strings. So the two callbacks were for each of the open windows. I just don't know how to tell which callback is corresponding to which open window. If I could tell whose callback it was, maybe I could cache and return an appropriate value.

Comment: You `getLabel` callback provide an instance of the [IRibbonControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribboncontrol.context) interface which provides the `Context` property. The context instance represents the window where your control is resided.

Comment: That's what it sounds like it **should** do. It doesn't appear to work in practice. Say I have two windows, Window A and Window B, and Window A is selected/active. The control resides in both windows (two Ribbon instances). When I pick Window B, `Invalidate` runs, and `getLabel` provides me a `Context`. This happens twice. I **should** get a callback with the `Context` for each Window, A and B. Instead, for the two callbacks, the `Context` points to Window B both times.

Comment: It seems somebody is calling the `Invalidate` method if you got the callback invoked twice. It should not be triggered for all windows if select any other window. Only for the currently selected window the callback is invoked. And when you switch to another window the callback will be triggered for a new one.

Comment: I am the one calling `Invalidate`. Maybe that's the problem. The sequence of operations is: 
(1) Add-in starts. On the `Startup` event, I subscribe to `Application.WindowActivate`. 
(2) `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject` runs. I create a new instance of my ribbon and store it local to the VSTO add-in class as `ribbon`. 
(3) When the user switches windows, `Application.WindowActivate` fires. I know which workbook and window this is. I fire `ribbon.Invalidate()` to refresh the state of the ribbon. 
(4) `getLabel` callback fires twice, both for the newly active window.

Comment: There is no need to call the `Invalidate` method. Is your callback called one time without `Invalidate`?

Comment: I commented out `Invalidate` and ran a test. I opened Excel Window A with Workbook A. I then opened a new Excel Window B. When Window B is selected, the ribbon callback occurs only one time, like you said - but the `ribbon.Context` references Window A. Not B.